# Как добавить картинку из Базы Данных в Django?

Tags: django

Я не могу вывести картинку из БД в мой HTML, все кроме этого выводится.

models.py

```
from turtle import title
from django.db import models

class Artiles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100, default="")
    anons = models.CharField('Анонс', max_length=250, default="")
    full_text = models.TextField('Характеристики')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Материал : {self.title}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Добавление материалов"
        verbose_name_plural = "Добавление материалов"
```

views.py

```
from distutils.log import error
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Artiles
from .forms import ArtilesForm
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

def news_home(request):
    news = Artiles.objects.order_by('-date')
    return render(request, 'news/news_home.html', {'news' : news})

class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Artiles
    template_name = 'news/details_view.html'
    context_object_name = 'article'

def create(request):
    global error
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArtilesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("home")
        else:
            error = "Форма была не верной"

    form = ArtilesForm()

    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }
    
    return render(request, 'news/create.html', data)
```

news_home.html

```
{% extends 'glav/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}Материалы{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="features">
        <h1>Материалы</h1>
        {% if news %}
            {% for i in news %}
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <h3>{{ i.title }}</h3>
                    <h2>{{ i.anons }}</h2>
                    <a href="{% url 'news-detail' i.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">Подробнее</a>
                    <img src="{{ i.image }}">
                </div>"
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <h3>Нет материалов</h3>
        {% endif %}
        {# Если не выводится основной блок, мы с помощью if выводим "Нет материалов" #}
        
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

details_view.html

```
{% extends 'glav/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ article.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="features">
        <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        <h2>{{ article.anons }}</h2>
        <p>{{ article.full_text }}</p>
        <p>{{ article.date }}</p>
        <img src="{{ article.image }}">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить .url для картинки

```
<img src="{{ article.image.url }}">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
src="/media/{{ i.image }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

добавь в urls.py строку:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое